# PHPUnit coverage mode causes fatal error "Cannot declare class ... because the name is already in use ..."

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I am building a `Laravel` project and right now, I am creating tests for it. I am using:

- Laravel `10.3.1`
- PHP `8.2.3`
- Xdebug `3.2.0`
- PHPUnit `9.6.4`
- Pest `1.22.5`

I cannot update PHPUnit to `^10.0` because of Pest ([read here](https://pestphp.com/docs/installation)).

However, I am facing the following problem. When I execute my tests either with `php artisan test` or with `./vendor/bin/pest` everything works fine and I get no error. But when I add the `--coverage` mode flag like this `XDEBUG_MODE=coverage ./vendor/bin/pest --coverage` I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class
> App\Vendor\MediaLibrary\ModifiedMedia, because the name is already in
> use in
> /Users/alex/Desktop/Bitbucket/Valet/dealbee-backend/app/Vendor/MediaLibrary/ModifiedMedia.php
> on line 8

I have already tried the following:

- `php artisan optimize:clear`
- `composer dump-autoload`
- `composer clear-cache`
- `php artisan cache:clear`
- Delete `/vendor` folder and run `composer install`

None of them helped me to resolve the issue. When I run `find . | grep ModifiedMedia.php` inside my repository, I only get one match, which is the only and single match: `./app/Vendor/MediaLibrary/ModifiedMedia.php`

This means there is no other class called `ModifiedMedia.php` in my repository.

I came across [this](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/4114) GitHub issue. They suggest setting `processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist` to `false` in the `phpunit.xml` file. I did not try that as it is not the best solution. But I did set `<coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">` to `false` just to test if this works or not, and yes, it does work. When `processUncoveredFiles` is set to false, I don't get the error above anymore.

But this cannot be the solution. I don't even know what `processUncoveredFiles` is doing and why it is working then.

Can anybody help me fix this problem without setting `processUncoveredFiles` or `processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist` to `false`?

Kind regards